# how to classified and digitalized huge amount of paper using python

Tags: python, nlp, document-classification

I have an archive papers in a company representing different business operation form different sections.
I want to scan all these documents and after that I want a way to classify all these scanned document into different category and sub-category based on custom preference such as (name, age, section, ..etc).

I want the end result to be digital files categorized according to the preferences that I set.

How can I do this using **Python NLP** or any other **machine learning approach**

Comment: This sounds like interesting, but challenging project. But what is your question? I suggest to check [help/on-topic].

Comment: I've the idea but I don't how to do it using python, I just updated the question.

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't want a specific or detailed answer for this, just a point to start or a technique to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this can be a basic pipeline:

- Scanning part: papers images preprocessing with `opencv` + text extraction using some OCR libraries (`pytesseract`, `easyOCR`);
- Topic extraction: get the desired information to classify the documents using e.g. `Spacy`
- Cathegorize using simply python, maybe `pandas`.